# How to keep certain rows based on a condition in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `df`. Below are two fields that pertain to my question

```
name   tardy
max      0
max      1
ben      0
amy      0
amy      1
sue      1
tyler    0
tyler    1
```

I would like to keep *only* the `name` of those who have both `tardy==0` **and** `tardy==1`. Thus, my desired output is the following

```
name   tardy
max      0
max      1
amy      0
amy      1
tyler    0
tyler    1
```

Getting rid of `name==sue` and `name==ben` makes it so that the only `name` showing up is for those who have both a `0` and `1` value for tardy.

I tried doing a `.loc`

`df[(df.tardy==0) & (df.tardy==1)]`

but this doesn't take into account filtering it by name.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For most general solution working for any data compare values of groups converted to `set`s with original and for avoid matching data like `0,1,0` compare by length if match:

```
vals = set([0,1])
m = df.groupby('name')['tardy'].transform(lambda x: set(x)==vals and len(x)==len(vals))
df = df[m]
print (df)
    name  tardy
0    max      0
1    max      1
3    amy      0
4    amy      1
6  tyler      0
7  tyler      1
```

Or solution with pandas functions - compare values if unique is same like set, compare lengths and also if matching values `0,1`:

```
vals = [0,1]
g = df.groupby('name')['tardy']
df = df[g.transform('size').eq(2) & g.transform('size').eq(2) & df['tardy'].isin(vals)]
print (df)
    name  tardy
0    max      0
1    max      1
3    amy      0
4    amy      1
6  tyler      0
7  tyler      1
```

Comment: Use `vals = {0,1}` and you can save yourself from `set(vals)` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby().nunique()`:

```
df[df.groupby('name')['tardy'].transform('nunique')==2]
```

Output:

```
    name  tardy
0    max      0
1    max      1
3    amy      0
4    amy      1
6  tyler      0
7  tyler      1
```

Comment: awesome. now how could I make the fields `is_tardy` and `not_tardy` based on the 0 and 1 values in `tardy`? For example the fields would be `name`, `is_tardy`, `not_tardy` instead of having a column with 0's and 1's

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `df.groupby().filter`, which filters the dataframe's groups based on a condition.

```
tardy_vals = {0, 1}
df.groupby('name').filter(lambda g: tardy_vals.issubset(g['tardy']))

    name  tardy
0    max      0
1    max      1
3    amy      0
4    amy      1
6  tyler      0
7  tyler      1
```